# Reload data in table view without harming animation

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView-based in-game shop.

Every cell has a "BUY" button which is mostly enabled and can be switched to "BOUGHT" if the item is a one-time purchase or can be disabled if there are not enough money.

Right now what I do is calling `reloadData` every time buy button is being pressed in order to update visible cells and the current cell itself. (I have to update all cells, because after purchase it is possible that there wont be enough money for visible item cells).

But it causes weird animation glitches, like when I click on one cell's buy button and animation finishes on another one.

I think this happens due to reusability of cells. So what I want to know is how to reload data in the whole table view without harming native animation.

The only thing I can think of is not to use reusable cells and cache them all, but I dont think this is a good programming practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your view layer and model layer are separate. There should be some non-view object that knows about each item; we'll call it `Item`.

Now, create an `ItemCell` (you probably have one already). That's your reusable cell. Hand it the `Item`. It should configure itself based on the data in there.

Use KVO, delegation, or notifications to let the cell observe its item. When the `Item` changes its status, the cell should update its own button.

When your cell is reused, you'll pass a new `item` to it. It should stop observing the previous one, and start observing the new one (and of course reconfigure itself to match the current status).

By separating the views (which are reusable and transitory) from the model (which is stable and long-lived), you get the performance benefits of cell reuse with correct animations and no need to call `reloadData`.

Comment: Well I thought this is a bad design when cell knows about it's model...

Comment: And I dont see how it helps me to update other cells in order to see if there are money for them

Comment: A cell knowing how to display a specific model class is excellent design and goes all the way back to SmallTalk. As long as it simply observes the model and continually provides a visual representation of it. A cell is just a view. If they need to know total money, you can hand them an "account" object.

Comment: Well but I still dont understand how to update other cells. Let's say I have 64 items in my shop. I store models for them in an array and then just creating a reusable cell for appropriate object. Once I click on a buy button you want me to update all 64 items let's say with some bool flag "canBeBought" and then only few of them will be observed since only 3-4 are visivle at a time. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: No, not at all. First, when you press the buy button, that should go to the controller, which should update the model. The current views should be observing the model and see something like "AccountBalanceDidChangeNotification" (or KVO or observer patterns, or whatever) and update themselves accordingly. If only 3 or 4 are visible at a time, then there will only be 3 or 4 (or maybe 5 or 6) views in existence. That's how recycling works.

Comment: It is quite natural for views to observe model objects that they display. For example, a "network active spinner view" should watch a "network status" model object and update itself whenever the status changes. The model should never know about the views, but the views can know about the parts of the model that they represent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117460/discussion-between-s1ddok-and-rob-napier).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `reloadCell` method in the cell class and loop through the table's `visibleCells` and update their UI that way.  That way they are not recreated (or re-used), they just have their relevant UI pieces that could have changed due to the new data updated.

Comment: This could work, but I will need to tell cell about it's model and that's what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: You set up the cells initially some how, just use that same methodology to do it again.